# It reads the file but it is not printing it properly when it sends it to a new file?

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I've been having a problem when it comes to printing the read file to a new file. So here's the example data from the finance file:

Capital

2215.281234

Weaver, Addison U.

902-6238 Purus, Avenue

Interest

22343.623428

Frost, Tana Y.

P.O. Box 902, 3494 Enim Road

When I ran it, all I was getting would be:

Name:

Address:

etc.

So after the "Name" or "Address" it doesn't display the respective name or add for that taxcode. However, it reads the file write; the problem it doesn't print the name and address on screen or in file. It'd be greatly appreciated, if someone could help me with this. The printing is the only problem that I'm having. Thanks in advance.

```
package fh;

import java.util.Scanner; import java.io.*;

public class fh {   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException

{

    String taxcode ,name , address;
    double tax = 0, income = 0;
    String financeAdd = "C:\\Users\\name\\workspace\\finance.txt";
    String correctRec = "C:\\Users\\name\\workspace\\taxrecords.txt";
    String wrongRec = "C:\\Users\\name\\workspace\\recorderror.txt";

    File file = new File(financeAdd);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

    PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(correctRec);
    PrintWriter outfile2 = new PrintWriter(wrongRec);

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        taxcode = s.nextLine();

        switch (taxcode)
        {
        case "Dividend":
            income = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            name = s.nextLine();
            address = s.nextLine();
            tax = (income * 1.25 - (income * 1.25 * 0.33)) * 0.22;   

            outfile.printf("%s%n%s%n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            break;

        case "Interest":
            income = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            name = s.nextLine();
            address = s.nextLine();
            tax = income * 0.22;  

            outfile.printf("%s%n%s%n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            break;

        case "Capital":
            income = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            name = s.nextLine();
            address = s.nextLine();
            tax = income * 0.50 * 0.22;  

            outfile.printf("%s%n%s%n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            break;

        default: 
            income = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            name = s.nextLine();
            address = s.nextLine();     

            outfile2.printf("%s%n%s%n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n","Name: ","Address: ", name, address);
            break;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Data Processed");

    s.close();
    outfile.flush();
    outfile.close();
    outfile2.flush();
    outfile2.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` line is wrong. Please use the following line instead.

```
System.out.printf("Name: %s\nAddress: %s\n", name, address);
```

What's wrong with your line is that you pass the string `"Name: "` and `"Address: "` as parameters to `printf` so that they are used to replace the 2 `%s`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I only have to tweak a bit and it is working now. I used to format my codes like this and this is the first time I had a problem.